# Modify the orchard search to display Meta Description, Link and Page Title

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I need to modify the existing search module in Orchard such that it displays the Title and Meta Description in the search List.

First of all i added the meta content part to my content types and it is working as i wanted.

Now i don't know how to index Meta content part as there is no option to select the content part in Search Settings. As it is not indexed so when i search on the website Meta content part doesn't appear in shape tracing. As i want to display title, link and meta description in the the search results so i manage to display Title and the link but i don't know how to Meta description in the search result.

Just to play around i added following Meta Parts and content types but its not working

```
<Place Parts_Meta="Content:2"/>
<Place Parts_Meta_Description="Content:3"/>
<Place Parts_Metas="Content:4"/>
```

and many more but it seems to be not working.

I think as meta tags are not showing in indexing so may be because of that it is not getting displayed. I don't know exactly how to proceed with it, Please help.!

The search settings does not have Meta Parts or even i can not add it to indexing from the content part.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to modify the search module for this, just adjust the placement for your content type. The search module displays content items using the "Summary" display type. Use Shape Tracing to find all the properties you need to hide.

So, for example, if your Content Type is called Page then you want this...

```
<Match ContentType="Page">
 <Match DisplayType="Summary">
  <Place ...add placement info... />
 </Match>
</Match>
```